# Troubleshooting Rolling Reboots on Desktop Machine

Tags: linux

I have a machine running Ubuntu that reboots itself every 20 minutes or so.  I watched the output of the `sensors` command and none of the thermal sensors or high (about 38.0C).  What else could cause this issue?  Which logs would help me?

Answer (score 1):

Run `ls -ltr /var/log` to see which log files were modified around the time of the reboot.  `/var/log/messages` may contain a clue just before the reboot, as could other log files such as `cron`.